# Regular expression for directory path

Tags: regex

I need regular expression to be able to check that string is directory path.
It should match

```
../../a/b/c
```

but not

```
../a/../b/c
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind it?

Comment: *I need regex ..* what a question !! free coding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem clearly based on the inputs then you may try that:

```
^(?:\.{2})?(?:\/\.{2})*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b4JChY/3/)

```js
const regex = /^(?:\.{2})?(?:\/\.{2})*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$/;

console.log(`../../a/b/c  =`+regex.test(`../../a/b/c`));
console.log(`../a/../b/c =`+regex.test(`../a/../b/c`));
console.log(`/a/b/../c =`+regex.test(`/a/b/../c`));
console.log(`/bbb/bcc= `+regex.test(`/bbb/bcc`));
console.log(`../b/b =`+regex.test(`../b/b`));
console.log(`../b/b =`+regex.test(`../b/b`));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want regex to match exactly `../../a/b/c` the regex for that is

```
\.\.\/\.\.\/a/b/c
```

The \ are used infront of .(period) because period is a metacharacter, to remove it's special property and use it as regular period \ is used.
If you want to replace a, b or c with any characters use character class `[a-z]` or you can use `\w`. In the case of \w it matches alphanumeric characters (A-Z a-z and 0-9).

Since I don't know for what purpose you want this I can just give the regular expression.

Comment: regular expression to be able to check that string is directory path (any network directory path) . I need to check string before passing it to windows cmd

Comment: @Abhishek Sorry I mistakenly added my code snippet to your answer... removed :)